# Laravel get current date using carbon with format without delimeter

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I want to format my date to be like this `yyyyMMddHHmmss`

Here is my currentcode

```
  $now = Carbon::now()->toString();
        $format='yyyyMMddHHmmss';
        //$parsed = Carbon::parse($now);
        $formatted = Carbon::parse($now);
        //$x = strtotime($now);
   dd($formatted);
```

I got a date like this

```
Carbon\Carbon @1580189543 {#223 ▼
  date: 2020-01-28 13:32:23.0 +08:00
}
```

If I modify my code like this

```
$formatted = Carbon::parse($now,$format);
    dd($formatted);
```

It says `Unknown or bad timezone (yyyyMMddHHmmss)` I just want my date to become like this `20200128 133223`

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use format on Carbon like this:

```php
Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis')
```

Comment: it is the same as `yyyyMMddHHmmss` sir ?

Comment: @Vince yes, you can test it by `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 0):

Your desire format is like

```
Carbon::now()->format('yymd his')
```

For details https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php